# do_shortcode('[mycbgenie_text_ad]') is working from PHP. But not [mycbgenie_text_ad] on TEXT widget

Tags: wordpress

> do_shortcode('[mycbgenie_text_ad]') ;

is working from PHP.

But the same as [shortcode] is not working  on TEXT widget

> [mycbgenie_text_ad]

Any clues?

I see none of the shortcodes are not working even a simple one with two line s of code! I have made sure a fresh wordpress installation.

Comment: By default Wordpress Shortcodes do not work in widget. You need to add custom function to do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your theme's functions.php

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```